# mysql server_time_zone or time_zone

Tags: mysql

am trying to change the time of my sql server:

```
     serve_time_zone=GMT Daylight Time 
     time_zone=SYSTEM
```

i have tried:

```
 SET TIME_ZONE='+01:00';
```

to get the correct time_zone, but when i restart server to take effect it resets itself.

i have searched and not found anything which will not reset itself. I have now downloaded Hiedi SQL to view my database.

I want to advance the time of the database by 1 hour 1+GMT

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;??

Comment: didnt do a thing :s
          
            SET GLOBAL time_zone ='+01:00';

Comment: try this:"You can set the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup with the --timezone=timezone_name option to mysqld_safe. You can also set it by setting the TZ environment variable before you start mysqld. The permissible values for --timezone or TZ are system dependent. Consult your operating system documentation to see what values are acceptable." taken from [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: lol, ive just read the exact same paragraph from the mysql manual, still i don't understand how to do this.  I want the timezone of: Europe/Amsterdam   which is GMT+01:00

Comment: just read about the lack of access to server variables on web hosting, so if the site goes live i will not be able to change this variable, so rather than using CURTIME() to get current time would i be best getting the time with date() with date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam')

sounds a better solution

Comment: Yes I do think so... It adds up some more lines in the code but it's the most reliable thing! good luck :)